# Java code to Search an Excel file with specific date and get the complete row which is matched

Tags: java, excel

I am new to Java coding. I am trying to find a Java code to retrieve the specific rows from an Excel file when it matches with my date. I found some code on the Web but not able to successfully use it for searching the Excel and retrieving the rows.

For example, my Excel sheet contains below

```
Empno       join_date   first_name  last_name  dob
123456      02/24/2017  John        Smiths     07/14/1990
324455      02/24/2017  David       Conner     12/29/1991
388787      03/14/2017  Sam         Brown      04/13/1991
```

I need to retrieve all rows which matched join_date as '02/24/2017' like below.

```
123456      02/24/2017  John        Smiths     07/14/1990
324455      02/24/2017  David       Conner     12/29/1991
```

Please help.

Comment: You might want to post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void readExcel() throws BiffException, IOException {
    String FilePath = "D:\\fake.xls";

    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);

    // the access to the sheet
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

    // To get the number of rows present in sheet
    int noOfRows = sh.getRows();

    // To get the number of columns present in sheet
    int noOfCols = sh.getColumns();
     for (int row = 0; row < noOfRows; row++) {
         if(sh.getCell(1, row).getContents()==your_date){
           for (int row_1 =row ; row_1 < noOfRows; row_1++) {
              for (int col = 0; col < noOfCols; col++) {
               System.out.print(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents() + "\t");
                 }
               System.out.println();
               }
           }
        }
}
```

> I Hope this will help you
>   You need to use JXL Library and XLS format file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But the code which you have given was not reading any value from excel sheet. Here is my complete code. Please check and let me know if need any changes required.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.setTime(new Date()); 
  c.add(Calendar.DATE, 90);
  String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
     int noOfRows = sh.getRows();
     int noOfCols = sh.getColumns();
         for (int row = 0; row < noOfRows; row++) {
          if(sh.getCell(1, row).getContents() == output){
            for (int row_1 =row ; row_1 < noOfRows; row_1++) {
               for (int col = 0; col < noOfCols; col++) {
                System.out.print(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents() + "\t");
}

Comment: This file support XLS format only. For XLSX format you need to use Apache POI library. Please make sure you are using XLS format